# Printing objects to html with a click function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add my student objects to the DOM one by one. I have now console logged everything how I would like it, I would just like to print each student objects one by one as the button is clicked. Once the button has been clicked three times I want to disable it. I had not problem doing this without objects, but now I am stuck. I know that I have grabbed any of the elements yet. I just don't know if it should be in the prototype or not? thanks

objects.js:

```
var Student = function(name, street, city, state, gpa, date) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = {
            street: street,
            city: city,
            state: state
        };
        this.gpa = gpa;
        this.date = date;


    };
    Student.prototype = {

        print: function() {
            console.log("Name: " + this.name);
            console.log("Street: " + this.address.street);
            console.log("City: " + this.address.city);
            console.log("State: " + this.address.state);
            console.log("Average GPA: " + this.getAverageGPA());
            console.log("Today's Date: " + this.date);
        },

        getAverageGPA: function() {
            var avgGPA = 0;
            for (var j = 0; j < this.gpa.length; j++) {
                avgGPA = avgGPA + this.gpa[j];
            }
            avgGPA = avgGPA / this.gpa.length;
            return avgGPA;
        }
    };


    function School() {

        this.createdStudents = [];
    }
    School.prototype = {

        addStudent: function(newStudent) {
            this.createdStudents.push(newStudent);

        },

        createStudent: function(name, street, city, state, gpa) {
            var newStudent = new Student(name, street, city, state, gpa);
            this.addStudent(newStudent);
            return newStudent;
        },

        printScores: function() {
            for (var i = 0; i < this.createdStudents.length; i++) {
                this.createdStudents[i].print();
            }
        },

        printStudents: function(){
            var a = 0;

            console.log(this.createdStudents[0]);

        }
    };
```

main.js:

```
(function(){
    console.log("start of function");

    /* Globals*/

        var clicks = 0;
        var button = document.querySelector('a');
        var school = new School();

        school.addStudent(new Student(
            "Walker",
            '123 South Drive',
            'Sarasota',
            'FL',
            [
                3.0,
                3.4,
                3.8
            ], date()));

        school.addStudent(new Student("Pinky",
            '876 Pebble Beach Lane',
            'Orange County',
            'CA',
            [
                2.5,
                2.4,
                3.8
            ], date()));

        school.printScores();

        console.log('---------New Object Entered-------------');

        school.addStudent(new Student(
            "Marisa",
            '5463 S Jersey Road',
            'Atlantic City',
            'NJ',
            [
                3.8,
                4.0,
                2.3
            ], date()));

        school.printScores();

            //Gets the correct date
            function date(){
            var today = new Date();
            var dd = today.getDate();
            var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!

            var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
            if(dd<10){dd='0'+dd} if(mm<10){mm='0'+mm} today = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy;
            return today;
        };

    })();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I do not believe that it should be the `Student`'s object responsability to know how it should be displayed and it shouldn't be the `School` object's responsability either. Data and presentation should be loosely coupled as much as possible. I would recommend you reading about [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

If however you want to keep these operation on the object themselves for some reason, you should at least extract the printing strategy from the object.

E.g. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9k89F/1)

JS

```
function DOMConsole(el) {
    this.el = el;
}

DOMConsole.prototype.log = function (obj) {
    var output = typeof obj === 'object'? JSON.stringify(obj) : obj,
        div = document.createElement('div');

    div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(output));

    this.el.appendChild(div);
};

function MyPrintableObj(someProp) {
    this.someProp = someProp;
}

MyPrintableObj.prototype.print = function (cons) {
    cons.log(this.someProp);
};
```

HTML

```
<div id="console"></div>

<script>
    (function () {
        var cons = new DOMConsole(document.getElementById('console')),
            pObj = new MyPrintableObject('test');

        pObj.print(cons); //print in DOM
        pObj.print(console); //print in console
    })();
</script>
```